# Looping through user info in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm just getting familiar with Parse's cloud code, but am having some trouble with a basic task: looping through one of array fields (called "newsFeed") for the logged in user. Here's what I've got:

**The Parse Code:**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("unseenItems", function(request, response) {

  // Get list of all news items for current user
  var user = Parse.User.current();
  var newsFeed = user.get("newsFeed");

  // Loop through news items and count number of unseen items
  // ("unseen" is a key for the array object, the value is 0 or 1)
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < newsFeed.length; i++) {
    sum += newsFeed[i].get("unseen"); 
  }
  console.log(sum);

  // Return sum of unseen items
  response.success(sum);

});
```

**The data structure**

newsFeed is an array of dictionaries, here's a sample:

```
[{"date":<date info>,
  "text":"Sample text",
  "seen":0},
  {"date":<date info>,
  "text":"More sample text",
  "seen":1}]
```

**The Objective-C code**

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"unseenItems"
                   withParameters:@{}
                            block:^(NSNumber *result, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error){
                                    self.unseenItems=[result intValue];
                                }
                            }];
```

And here's the error I'm getting in XCode: `Error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get' at main.js:84:24 (Code: 141, Version: 1.5.0)`

Any pointers on where to go from here would be fantastic. Thanks for reading!

Comment: It says your object does not have a get method, try using object.attributes.unseen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the error was just in basic JavaScript usage. To get inside the dictionary that's inside the array, here's what worked:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < newsFeed.length; i++) {
    sum += newsFeed[i]["unseen"]; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're saying that newsFeed is an array of integers, like `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`.  If so, then the fix is easy

```
sum += newsFeed[i];   // no "get" needed on an array of ints
```

Comment: Hi @danh, thanks for the reply! The field "newsFeed" is actually an array of dictionary objects. I'll add more about this to the question.